# Tiles 2.2.2 in Spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles

Iam new to Tiles and Spring framework. I am using Tiles 2.2.2 and STS 3.1.0.RELEASE.

My servlet-context.xml is as follows :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->

    <!--
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sivalabs.web" />

    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
       <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
     </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
       <beans:property name="definitions">
         <beans:list>
           <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
         </beans:list>
       </beans:property>      
    </beans:bean>   
</beans:beans>
```

I am receiving following error at the very last line :

The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Can some one guide me, where the error is actually situated and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<beans:bean>` try using just `<bean>`.

```
<bean id="viewResolverTiles"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also while specifying tiles view resolver, you might also want to declare TileConfigure which points to your tiles.xml file:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Read: [Spring 3 MVC Tiles Integration Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/)